# Unit test a callback that uses Handlers

Tags: android, unit-testing

I created this short class which delivers a response to a listener after executing a certain process. To make this a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I modified my *handleMessage(Message)* function to sleep for 5 seconds and return a random string when done instead of actually connecting to a remote host.

```
public class MyService {
    private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    private final HandlerThread mInboxHandlerThread;
    private final Handler mInboxHandler;
    private final List<Handler> mListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyService() {
        mInboxHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("Incoming data handler");
        mInboxHandlerThread.start();

        mInboxHandler = new Handler(mInboxHandlerThread.getLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                MyService.this.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };
    }

    public final void inform(Message msg) {
        if (mInboxHandler != null) {
            mInboxHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "mInboxHandler is null");
        }
    }

    public final void registerListener(Handler listener) {
        mListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public final void unregisterListener(Handler listener) {
        mListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    final void notifyOutboxHandlers(int what, int arg1, int arg2, Object obj) {
        if (mListeners.isEmpty()) {
            Log.w(TAG, String.format("No listener to handle outgoing message (%d)", what));
        } else {
            for (Handler handler : mListeners) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, what, arg1, arg2, obj);
                msg.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Mimic long-running service execution
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                notifyOutboxHandlers(COMMAND_RESPONSE, 0, 0, "<SUCCESS/>");
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

This class is working. I just need to write a unit test and make sure that the listener (of type Handler) can be triggered from the service. My view (of type Activity) layer is as simple as this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Handler.Callback {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private MyService mMyService = null;
    private TextView mMessagesView = null;
    private Handler mHandler = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cc);
        mMessagesView = findViewById(R.id.messages);

        mMyService = new MyService();
        mHandler = new Handler(this);
        mMyService.registerListener(mHandler);

        Message test = new Message();
        test.what = COMMAND_REQUEST;
        test.arg1 = 1;
        test.arg2 = 2;
        test.obj = "test";
        mMyService.inform(test);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        String messages = mMessagesView.getText().toString();
        mMessagesView.setText(messages + "\nTransactionManager: " + msg.obj);

        switch (msg.what) {
            case COMMAND_RESPONSE:
                Log.d(TAG, "got response from controller");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMyService.unregisterListener(mHandler);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

So finally, my issue is, how do I unit test this callback function? How do I make sure that the handler in the view layer gets triggered properly. Specifically, I want to test/assert that the reply from the service is a `<SUCCESS/>`.

By referring to other stack overflow posts, I was able to create this test script but does not work even:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    private MyService mMyService;
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Mock
    private Handler.Callback mHandlerCallback;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Handler.Callback> callbackCaptor;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mMyService = new MyService();
        when(mHandlerCallback.handleMessage(any(Message.class)))
                .thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallback() {
        String message = "test";

        Message test= new Message();
        test.what = COMMAND_REQUEST;
        test.arg1 = 1;
        test.arg2 = 2;
        test.obj = message;

        mHandler = new Handler(callbackCaptor.capture());
        mMyService.registerListener(mHandler);
        mMyService.inform(test);

        assertTrue(callbackCaptor instanceof Handler.Callback );
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Testing asynchronous code can be tricky because the test runner does not wait for asynchronous tasks to complete. In this case, you are trying to test a callback that gets invoked by an asynchronous operation.

One way to do this is to use `CountDownLatch` which is a concurrency tool in Java that allows one thread to wait until a certain condition is met in another thread. (see also "[**Guide to CountDownLatch in Java**](https://www.baeldung.com/java-countdown-latch)" by [**Eugen Baeldung**](https://www.baeldung.com/about/))

As an example, you can modify your test class with:

```java
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    private MyService mMyService;
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Mock
    private Handler.Callback mHandlerCallback;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Message> messageCaptor;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mMyService = new MyService();
        when(mHandlerCallback.handleMessage(any(Message.class)))
                .thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallback() throws InterruptedException {
        // Create a CountDownLatch with a count of 1
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // Override the handleMessage method to count down the latch when the message is received
        mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                messageCaptor.setValue(msg);
                latch.countDown();
                return true;
            }
        });

        mMyService.registerListener(mHandler);

        // Send a message to the service
        Message test = new Message();
        test.what = COMMAND_REQUEST;
        test.arg1 = 1;
        test.arg2 = 2;
        test.obj = "test";
        mMyService.inform(test);

        // Wait for the latch to count down (up to 10 seconds)
        boolean received = latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Assert that the message was received
        assertTrue(received);

        // Assert that the received message is what you expected
        assertEquals("<SUCCESS/>", messageCaptor.getValue().obj);
    }
}
```

`CountDownLatch` is used to pause the execution of the test method until the callback is invoked. The latch is counted down in the `handleMessage` method of the handler, which is the method that is called when the message is sent to the handler. If the callback is invoked within 10 seconds, then the test passes.
The `ArgumentCaptor` is used to capture the `Message` object that is sent to the callback so that you can assert that it is what you expected.

Make sure to adjust the time in `latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` accordingly based on how long the operation takes in your service. If the operation takes longer than the provided timeout, the test will fail.

The difference with your original code:

1. **CountDownLatch:** In the updated code, a `CountDownLatch` is created with a count of 1. The purpose of this latch is to pause the execution of the test method until the callback is invoked. When the callback is invoked, the latch is counted down. If the latch is counted down within the specified timeout (10 seconds in this case), then the test passes. If the callback is not invoked within the timeout, the test fails. This is a common technique used to test asynchronous code.
2. **Handler Creation:** In the original code, the `Handler` is created with a `Callback` that is captured by an `ArgumentCaptor`. This is done to capture the `Callback` object so that it can be verified later. However, in the updated code, the `Handler` is created with a `Callback` that counts down the `CountDownLatch` when it receives a message. This is done to signal that the callback has been invoked.
3. **Assertion:** In the original code, the test asserts that the `Callback` is an instance of `Handler.Callback`. However, in the updated code, the test asserts that the `Message` received by the callback is what was expected. This is a more meaningful test because it verifies that the service behaves as expected, not just that it calls the callback.
4. **Message Capturing:** In the updated code, `ArgumentCaptor` is used to capture the `Message` object that is sent to the callback. This is done so that you can assert that the message is what you expected. In the original code, there is no such capturing.
5. **Exception Handling:** The updated test method declares that it throws `InterruptedException`. This is required because `latch.await()` can throw this exception if the current thread is interrupted while waiting for the latch to count down.